# Visual Studio Test Project Start Up Event?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, unit-testing

My projects all use StructureMap as a container/IoC. I leverage this in things like repository patterns. In my unit test project, I've implemented test repositories when it makes sense. In order for structure map to know what concrete implementation to use, I need to initialize the container and run registration of types. I'm looking for a place to call my IoC.Initialize() in a unit test project. Outside of unit test, for example, in a web project, I can initialize my IoC container/registration from the Global.asax. I'm looking for a Unit Test equivalent of a Global.asax (e.g. static void main, a way to wire into the main start up event entry point of Unit tests). I've got around this by using a base class for all my tests, and initializing in there, so any test that is run ends up initializing the IoC container if it's not already initialize... but it's very hack-ish IMHO, so I'm looking for a cleaner way.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE/ANSWER**

The following is the solution I implemented per Matthew's response.

```
<TestClass()>
Public Module Main

    Public Property TestContext As TestContext

    <AssemblyInitialize()>
    Public Sub Initialize(_TestContext As TestContext)

        TestContext = _TestContext
        IoC.Initialize()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `AssemblyInitializeAttribute`. You can decorate a method with this in a class in your assembly and it will be run once before any tests in that assembly get run.

Comment: Perfect. To add clarity for anyone stumbling across this question, I added an update to the question above with my specific implementation of the answer (e.g. a method with that decorator needs a specific signature, and the class/module it's in needs to be decorated with the TestClassAttribute). Thanks Matthew!!!